# How to update Plotly Scatter3d graph in streamlit?

Tags: python, plotly, scatter3d

I am stuck off a point about updating plotly **Scatter3d**. I have a bunch of x, y, and z value of a dataframe. Firstly, User loads first dataframe file. Figure plots the first dataframe as you can see
[image: Figure1]

Then, user loads second dataframe. However, there are two graphs. Second dataframe does not plotted on first graph. Its create second graph. [image: Figure 2]

there are two graph same time. [image: Figure 3]

How can update the graph using Figure 1?.

Comment: Can you please add a minimum working example?